# ¿Cómo hacer que android studio muestre el nombre de los parametros?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que se vea así

```
Toast.makeText(context: this, text: "El segundo valor debe ser diferente de 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Antes me mostraba `context:` y `text:` pero sin querer le di en deshabilitar y ahora no se como habilitarlo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sigue este camino `File > Settings > Editor > Inlay Hints > Java > Parameter hints` y luego activa la opción `Show parameter hints`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si aparece deshabilitada, primero tendrás que seleccionar Java aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: broooooooooooo al chile no mames nadie me pudo dar una mejor respuesta que tu al chile me dan ganas de abrazarte

Comment: pero solo me los muestra pero no me los escribe o me los pone como le hago

Comment: Es que no debes escribirlos. Si los escribes te va a dar error porque esa sintaxis no está permitida. Solamente sirve como ayuda para que sepas qué es cada parámetro

Comment: pero antes si me los escribia y mi app no abre por que dice que falla

Comment: No, debe haber sido tu imaginación. No puede ni debe escribirlos. La causa de la falla es otra. Lo que debes hacer es crear una nueva pregunta mostrando el mensaje de error y entonces podrán ayudarte a solucionarlo